# React Native - how to play a MPEG-TS video reading from UDP stream

Tags: react-native, udp, webrtc, datagram

**Context:**
I'm building a React Native mobile app and connect it to a GoPro camera. I'm trying to use Preview Streaming feature which allows the mobile app to live-preview the video recorded from the camera.
**Technical info.**
The GoPro camera will send data to the mobile app through port 8554 via UDP protocol. Data is in MPEG-TS format. I can receive the datagram already, but it's in binary data. To play the video (using WebRTC view), I'm trying to convert the data into a video stream, which I cannot right now
**Question**
How to convert MPEG-TS datagram received from UDP into a playable video stream? Note that I'm building a React Native app :)